# React-Native: Downloading and Running external Javascript files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lua, coronasdk

I'm **very** new to React-Native. I've moved from CoronaSDK. There, in CoronaSDK, there's a [plugin](https://marketplace.coronalabs.com/corona-plugins/deploy) that allows you to download and run external lua files or lua strings and run them.

I was wondering if there was a similar feature, whether internal or external, to allow for downloading and running Javascript(React) files and run them after app build?

I saw services like CodePush, that allows for full app updates deployment. However, I wanted to see if there was something similar to downloading and running individual files.

Comment: I believe Apple disallows this, so you're targeting iOS, you may not want to do this.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Apple has loosened that restriction a bit. See 2.4.5 (iv) [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).